# Qt Signal/Slots: passing function returning pointer as receiver argument: is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, signals-slots

Say I have the function...

```
const QMainWindow* MainWindow::getThis(){
    return this;
}
```

would it be possible to call this function for the third argument of my SIGNAL/SLOT connection...

```
QAction* myAction = new QAction("my action!");
connect(myAction, &QAction::triggered, getThis(), &MainWindow::someAction);
```

(qt creator doesnt like this)

Comment: what is the meaning of `qt creator doesnt like this`?

Comment: mainwindow.cpp:40:5: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
qobject.h:242:43: note: candidate function [with Func1 = void (QAction::*)(bool), Func2 = void (MainWindow::*)()] not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'const QMainWindow *' to derived class pointer 'const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (MainWindow::*)()>::Object *' (aka 'const MainWindow *') for 3rd argument

Comment: Is someAction() a const function? Since you require it to not modify MainWindow

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410130/no-matching-function-for-qobjectconnect
It may happen that in the place where you are trying to make a connection QObject is not inherited and Q_OBJECT macro is not declared.